# python3 mysql.connector - get results/output from cursor

Tags: python-3.x, mysql-python

my sql commands are working for instance to truncate table - but my load data command isn't actually inserting any records - how can I confirm py is reading my input file correctly or at all?

```
cursor.execute("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/user/mongo_exported_users.csv' INTO TABLE tbl.users IGNORE 1 LINES")

row_count = cursor.rowcount
for i in range(row_count):
    line = cursor.fetchone()
    print(line)
mydb.close()
print("Done")
```

The output of the fetchone is just None for all rows so IDK whats going on!

Comment: Can you commit the data ?

Comment: ? not sure what you mean

Comment: Check the answer once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL transactions have to be managed by `commit`. add the below line before closing the connection.

`mydb.commit()`

or

you can make `autocommit` just after the connection as shown below

`mydb.autocommit = true`

This should do the job

Comment: Thanks - that does indeed seem to do the job!

Comment: one more question though - the line = cursor.fetchone() still prints out None and my data in the db is all put into one column!

Comment: I can't comment anything more than my answer without looking at the table structure and the CSV data